# Django static file not found

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am struggling using the static file app in django 2.1.

Using the django-admin findstatic, the file is found:

```
$ sudo python3 /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 leaflet/leaflet.css
Found 'leaflet/leaflet.css' here:
  /opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/leaflet/static/leaflet/leaflet.css
```

Using the url below, my browser shows "The requested URL /Project/static/leaflet/leaflet.css was not found on this server.":

```
http://myserver/Project/static/leaflet/leaflet.css
```

However, using a different file from a different directory:

```
$ sudo python3 /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 admin/css/fonts.css
Found 'admin/css/fonts.css' here:
  /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.1.1-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/fonts.css
```

The file is accessible in my browser using the url:

```
http://myserver/Project/static/admin/css/fonts.css
```

Edit1: if I create any file in the folder /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.1.1-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/ such as file.txt , I can access it immediately via the url http://myserver/Project/static/admin/file.txt

Edit2: Accessing http://myserver/Project/static/admin/ gives a 403 error whereas accessing http://myserver/Project/static/leaflet/ gives a 404 error

What can I do to troubleshoot this issue?

I use DJANGO 2.1

My settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/Project/static/'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: on deployment you must call collectstatic command

Comment: @vorujack, I created the STATIC_ROOT parameter to point to an empty directory, then ran the command "collectstatic". Files are copied but I still cannot access file such as http://myserver/Project/static/leaflet/leaflet.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I hope this help somebody: My apache conf file had an Alias pointing  to /opt/bitnami/apps/django/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.1.1-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/admin/static . That explain why the static files under admin were accessible. I changed so it point to my STATIC_ROOT:

```
Alias /Project/static '/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/staticfolder/'
<Directory /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/staticfolder>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```